# Maven puts downloaded jars in root of eclipse projectq

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've created a web application project using maven. When maven downloads dependencies specified in pom.xml, it puts jars in root of eclipse project, so it looks like this:

[image]

I want all the jars to be in eclipse's JRE System Library folder.
Does anybody know how to specify this in maven?

Comment: Eclipse Version? What happens, if you delete the eclipse project configuration files (.project, .classpath) and import the project via 'Existing Maven Projects'? The maven dependencies should be located in another virtual directory named 'Maven Dependencies'.

Comment: Based on the things M2_REPO and the missing icon for a Maven project i can see that you didn't import the Maven project into eclipse. this will not work. You need to import the maven project into Eclipse using m2e Eclipse Plugin.